# How to get current template engine in custom template filter in Django?

Tags: django

How to get current or default template engine here?

```
@register.filter
def myfilter(instance):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the **instance** of the default template engine (the first configured) doing the following:

```
from django.template.engine import Engine

current_engine = Engine.get_default()
```

More information:
http://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/templates/api.html#django.template.Engine.get_default

An extract of that documentation:

> static Engine.get_default()
>
> Returns the underlying Engine from the first configured
>   DjangoTemplates engine. Raises ImproperlyConfigured if no engines are
>   configured.
>
> It’s required for preserving APIs that rely on a globally available,
>   implicitly configured engine. Any other use is strongly discouraged.

See also the source code of that staticmethod:
http://django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django/template/engine.html#Engine.get_default

Answer (score 0):

```
from settings import TEMPLATES

TEMPLATES[0]['BACKEND']
```

or

```
from django.template.backends.django import DjangoTemplates
```